# Turn result based on column with date

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a column with dates. Those dates I want to assign to new columns "attended" and "upcoming", based on past 5 working days and upcoming 5 working days.
I want to have following results shown:

```
column "attended" -> 1 for past and 0 if upcoming 
column "upcoming" -> 1 for upcoming and 0 if in the past.
```

I tried to solve it via conditional formatting, but this is not giving me the result I am looking for.

Comment: Please add a screenshot to better illustrate what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The following formulae might be of some assistance. For these, I consider the evaluated date is placed in cell F3 (please do change suitably):

- For "*attended*" column (then drag down as needed):
  `=IF(IFERROR(DATEDIF(F3,WORKDAY.INTL(NOW(),-5),"D"),0)<=0,0,1)`
- For "*upcoming*" column (then drag down as needed):
  `=IF(IFERROR(DATEDIF(F3,WORKDAY.INTL(NOW(),5),"D"),0)<=0,1,0)`

These formulae produce the following results:

[image]

Hope it helps to solve your problem.

Kind regards.